# how to linstall texlive without lcdf-typetools

Tags: installing

For some reasons (i.e, openmpi conflicts with lcdf-typetools [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061421/lcdf-typetools-conflicts-with-openmpi-in-gentoo?noredirect=1#comment42666834_27061421) [b](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1004598-highlight-.html), which is not the main topic here), I need to install texlive of any version without lcdf-typetools. Anyone please shed lights on how to do this? What is the consequence that install texlive without lcdf-typetools?

note:
  I have found that both texlive2012 and texlive 2014 requires lcdf-typetools

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I use gentoo linux, which requires user compiling every single package from source. But this quiestion is independent from OS. e.g., RHEL-based os provides  texlive-lcdf-typetools.rpm, which will be problematic if installed in a system with openmpi installed.

Comment: If you are using GNU/Linux, I imagine you should be able to install using upstream's installer. However, (a) I have not tried this, and (b) if there is really a conflict, the conflict will be there - you just won't be told about it. I can't tell from the info in the links what exactly the nature of the conflict is.

Comment: @cfr Solving the conflict is not the main topic here, I just wish to know if lcdf-typetools can be separated from texlive and what the consequences if lcdf-typetools is not present.

Comment: I can't see how it can possibly be required to *use* TeX Live. It includes tools which are extremely useful in installing and finding information about fonts. I don't know if XeTeX or LuaTeX needs any of it, though I would be surprised. See http://ctan.org/pkg/lcdf-typetools.

Comment: It doesn't follow that this will create a conflict on RHEL-based systems, by the way. It depends on how things are packaged.